# Can't use reflect.Type as comparable with generics in go 1.18

Tags: go, generics

I've tried to implement a generic `Set` in go 1.18. I've used a map from the generic type to `bool` to implement it. this requires me to add the builtin constraint `comparable` to the type parameter:

```golang
type Set[T comparable] struct {
    values map[T]bool
}
```

When I try to create a set of `reflect.Type` the following error is raised:
`"reflect.Type does not implement comparable"`.

I would understand this error, since `reflect.Type` is an interface; However, I know that using `reflect.Type` as the key of a map is explicitly allowed.

Is there any way to get around this problem other than changing the implementation of the set?

Comment: in Go 1.18 interfaces don't implement `comparable` (the constraint) but *are comparable* (as defined in the language specs), so as you already found out, you can use them as map keys directly but can't instantiate type params constrained by `comparable`

Comment: This quirk of the Go 1.18 implementation is currently being (heatedly) discussed in the Go issue tracker, and one of the main use cases for this to work is precisely `reflect.Type` as map key, so there's good chances that at some point in the future this contradiction will be resolved; but as of today, you're stuck with this

Comment: soon: [proposal: spec: allow basic interface types to instantiate comparable type parameters](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56548)